# hide div elements when size gets too large

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a breadcrumb structure and the elements are getting large.
I would like to hide several breadcrumbs when the size of the breadcrumbs is bigger than the available size. Which command can i use to check if the size of a div is greater than the available space. I have tried to capture an overflow event but this did not work. The .width on my div always return the full size of the screen although when i debug in chrome is says a smaller value...

any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Edit:

```
function trimBreadcrumbs()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("mnav-emtUl");
    var width = x.offsetWidth;
alert(width);
}
```

this return the full width of the screen although in google chrome it says 200px...

Comment: Do you have any fiddle or pieces of code?

Answer (score 0):

if you didn't set `width`, it is inherited as `width=100%`. So this is absolutly correct. Set `display:inline-block;` for you're breadcumb navigation and it will return the real size.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="demo">Click the button to display this window's height and width (NOT including toolbars and scrollbars).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


function myFunction()
{
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
x = document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML="Width: " + w + " Heigth: " + h;
}
```